# while starting minishift give error during 'cluster up'

Tags: minishift

[i run the command minishift start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExHRl.png)

```
Error during 'cluster up' execution: Error starting the cluster. ssh command error:
command : /var/lib/minishift/bin/oc cluster up --base-dir /var/lib/minishift/base --image 'openshift/origin-${component}:v3.11.0' --public-hostname 192.168.42.204 --routing-suffix 192.168.42.204.nip.io
err     : exit status 1
output  : Getting a Docker client ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11.0 is available ...
Pulling image openshift/origin-cli:v3.11.0
E1105 12:27:47.021019    2182 helper.go:173] Reading docker config from /home/docker/.docker/config.json failed: open /home/docker/.docker/config.json: no such file or directory, will attempt to pull image docker.io/openshift/origin-cli:v3.11.0 anonymously
Image pull complete
Pulling image openshift/origin-node:v3.11.0
E1105 12:27:52.443620    2182 helper.go:173] Reading docker config from /home/docker/.docker/config.json failed: open /home/docker/.docker/config.json: no such file or directory, will attempt to pull image docker.io/openshift/origin-node:v3.11.0 anonymously
Pulled 5/6 layers, 86% complete
Pulled 6/6 layers, 100% complete
Extracting
Image pull complete
Checking type of volume mount ...
Determining server IP ...
Using public hostname IP 192.168.42.204 as the host IP
Checking if OpenShift is already running ...
Checking for supported Docker version (=>1.22) ...
Checking if insecured registry is configured properly in Docker ...
Checking if required ports are available ...
Checking if OpenShift client is configured properly ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11.0 is available ...
Starting OpenShift using openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11.0 ...
```

Comment: How is this programming-related?

Answer (score 1):

try adding this configuration before starting minishift

```
minishift config set docker-opt "add-registry=quay.io"
```

then

```
minishift start
```